# Transaction verification exception while invoking an flow in corda

Tags: corda

I have an contract which consumes an input of typeA to produce output of typeB and my contract looks similar as shown

```
  override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val commandCreate = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands.Create>()
        requireThat {

 "One input state should be there for TypeB" using (tx.inputStates.size==1)
            "One output states should be there for TypeB" using (tx.outputStates.size==1)
            "Input State should be a TypeA" using (tx.getInput(0) is TypeAState)
            "Output State should be a TypeB" using(tx.getOutput(0) is TypeBState)
            "TypeA id Number should not be empty" using((tx.getInput(0) as TypeAState).idNumber.isNotEmpty())
```

}

and I get the following error while invoking the flow

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractRejection:
>   Contract verification failed: Required
>   com.example.contract.PolicyContract.Commands.Create command, contract:
>   com.example.contract.PolicyContract, transaction:
>   B2AE49DEDFE882C9DDBA9ECB35740A689CFDC4F8ED78DD43D912FDC9DC5DC2C4

My flow looks something like this

```
 val txCommand = Command(TypeBContract.Commands.Create(), listOf(me.owningKey))
            val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                    .addInputState(typeARef)
                    .addOutputState(outputState, TYPEB_CREATION_CONTRACT_ID)
                    .addCommand(txCommand)
```

Where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `requireSingleCommand`. When you create a transaction with input states, the command that the input state was included within another transaction will load here as well.

To solve this use `tx.commandsOfType<YourType>()` or whatever the syntax is. This will not throw an exception. This solution is what you should use when there are inputs and outputs in a transaction.

The exception is due to `single` being called in `requireSingleCommand`.